# MySQL: query to run to make MySQL use GMT/UTC?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Is there a SQL query I can run to make MySQL use GMT/UTC for CURRENT_TIME, NOW, etc.?

I'm building a CodeIgniter application and want to run this query in the constructor of my base model.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this automatically by extending the CI_Controller class using MY_Controller ([Manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html))

```
$this->db->query("SET time_zone = 'GMT'");
```

Or you can use the `pre_controller` hook ([Manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html))

Comment: Ben, I will create a base model (will exdend CI_Model) and have all my models extend my base model. Should I just use double quotes since `'GMT'` is wrapped in single quotes (I think your sample is missing a closing single quote)?

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon! Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, correct. The answer's been fixed, but well spotted. Extending CI_Model will also work too.

Comment: By the way, what's the difference between UTC and GMT? I'm getting a "Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'GMT'"

Comment: Is this the same: `$this->db->query("SET time_zone='+00:00';");`?

Comment: The term Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) does not have a precise definition at the subsecond level, but it is often considered equivalent to UTC. Coordinated Universal Time (abbreviated UTC) is the primary time standard by which the world regulates clocks and time. It is one of several closely related successors to Greenwich Mean Time. From wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time